# "Property or method "products" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render" Error in Vue App

Tags: node.js, rest, vue.js, axios

I have a products JSON array at my localhost REST endpoint that I want to display in my Vue App causing axios. I have defined an empty array inside "data" to make it reactive, but I keep getting the "products" is not defined on the instance" error,
Screenshot:
[image]
My Products.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <div class="card" v-bind:key="p.id" v-for="p in products">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>{{ p.name }}</h3>
        <p>Cost: {{ p.price }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      products: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/products/all")
      .then((response) => {
        this.products = response.data.results;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
};

</script>
```

My App.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
        <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <Products v-bind:products="products"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Products from './components/Products.vue';
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Products
  },
  data(){
    return{
      msg: 'Check 123'
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

My main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'


Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('products', require('./components/Products.vue'));
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  data: {
      products: []
    }
  }).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Assuming that you are using the Vue CLI and Single File Components (which it looks like), in addition to the changes suggested to App.vue in the answer, you can remove ```Vue.component(...)``` and ```data: {}``` from main.js.

Comment: I've made the changes you recommended and in the answer, and the error no longer appears. But my products is still "undefined" when I inspect it.

Comment: Solved, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `products` are defined and fetched inside `Products.vue` component there's no need to pass them as prop, so `App.vue` should look like  :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
        <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <Products />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Products from './components/Products.vue';
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Products
  },
  data(){
    return{
      msg: 'Check 123'
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Thank you! I made the changes and the error no longer appears. However, my products array is still not populating. It still says "undefined" when I inspect it. When I hit my endpoint, it gives me the array. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: My products.vue: ///// export default {
  data() {
    return {
      products: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getProducts();
  },
  methods: {
    getProducts() {
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:8080/products/all")
        .then((response) => {
          this.products = response.data.results;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};

Comment: App.vue exactly like you said, and no changes in main.js as well

Comment: I think you should just do `this.products = response.data`?

Comment: That's it, you win. Show me your ways master. How do I get as good as you are lmao. I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Just keep watching the new questions and try to answer if you can else look to other ones answers to learn